# Asterisk in string json file Missing, Cypress

Tags: json, api, cypress

I want to use an api call which the header has a key contains Asterisk "R7x9hav*InqUHZhhb^D^" . I'm using a json file with all my keys, but this one ends as "R7x9havInqUHZhhb^D^" and "InqUHZhhb^D^" part appears as *Italic*. How can I have the existing Asterisk in string?
This only happens in Cypress.

Answer (score 1):

Check json quote/ json escape or use this tool(first one in google)

https://www.freeformatter.com/json-escape.html